# How can I invoke different methods for certain text combinations in a single UILabel on a user's touch event?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

As you can see below I have a `UITableViewCell` created and I have an `UILabel` and a `UIImage` in it. What I am finding hard to do is to invoke two separate methods on the touch action for "John Doe" and "The Beach".

After clicking on "John Doe" I want the user to be directed to the profile page of John Doe and after clicking the "The Beach" I need to direct it to that "Beach" event.

How can I identify two different touches on a single `UILabel`?

my `UITableViewCell` looks like this

[image]

Comment: Why not consider 2 UILabels , One UILabel for "John dow he was g......" and the second UILabel for "The Beach", is there any specific reason to make the line  fit in One UIlabel?

Comment: Because the label is dynamically populated and If I add two labels there I would struggle to position them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a UILabel replacement which supports adding links.

https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel Seems to be a very popular drop in replacement for UILabel adding support for easy link detection among many other useful features.

This would save you trying to write one yourself. You could also just use it to see how they do it if you want to do something similar with your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your reference. The thing is that I'm using xamarin.iOS for my development. (http://xamarin.com/platform)

Comment: There are bindings for MonoTouch: https://github.com/lipka/MonoTouch.TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *label = ...
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
      [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

**Otherwise You can use a UIButton, make it transparent, i.e. custom type without an image or name, and add a UILabel on it (centered). then use as a normal button by connecting IBAction.**

Comment: I'm not sure how I can achieve my objective according to your suggestion?

Comment: you can go for the second option its very simple i think. use a UIButton without name or background image above the label where u want to trigger the action.

Comment: if u use the button without name or background it will be transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ResponsiveLabel](https://github.com/hsusmita/ResponsiveLabel).You can provide regex string for making certain words clickable. For example to highlight the words in quotes, you can configure this way.

```
PatternTapResponder stringTapAction = ^(NSString *tappedString) {
  NSLog(@"tapped string = %@",tappedString);
};
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *expression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:@"(\"\\w+\")" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive  error:&error];
PatternDescriptor *descriptor = [[PatternDescriptor alloc]initWithRegex:expression withSearchType:PatternSearchTypeAll withPatternAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor brownColor],RLTapResponderAttributeName:stringTapAction}];
[self.responsiveLabel enablePatternDetection:descriptor];
```